# Crash when setting property in UIColor subclass

Tags: ios, swift, crash, uikit, uicolor

I am currently trying to create a subclass of `UIColor`, since I need to enrich it with a couple of properties for my purposes. As soon as I try to set any custom properties on my subclass, the app will crash with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception. Is this expected? Am I missing something?

This is the code I've tried:

```
class MyColorClass: UIColor {

    var customProperty: String!

    convenience init(fromColor color: UIColor) {
        self.init(cgColor: color.cgColor)
        self.customProperty = "rgfgb" // crash
    }

}

MyColorClass(fromColor: UIColor.black)
```

Example playground: https://ufile.io/ejmrwst4

Comment: it is not crashing in that line. Is anything I miss?

Comment: @VinuJacob how do you mean? It's crashing for me both in an app as well as in a playground

Comment: @VinuJacob I updated the original post with an example playground. Maybe you could confirm if this playground is crashing or not crashing for you?

Comment: It works perfectly in both, application and playground i thought you've delete your derived data and clean project and delete application then rebuild it, may be resolve crashing.

Comment: Really weird, I've tried all that and it's still crashing. Also found a blogpost describing this exact problem: https://cjwirth.com/tech/you-cant-subclass-uicolor . Are you possibly running Xcode 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after digging around a bit, here's what I found out:

#### What is happening

So it seems it is not easily possible to subclass `UIColor`, since it is part of a so-called "class cluster". [This article](https://cjwirth.com/tech/you-cant-subclass-uicolor) describes it really well.

The gist of the matter is that, internally, Apple has several (private) subclasses of `UIColor`, and `UIColor` itself is designed as an abstract factory class which returns one of the concrete subclasses to you. Apple describes all this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html). Therefore, if you subclass `UIColor`, some functionality is missing since it's not designed to be used directly.

#### The solution

Theoretically, it is possible to create a subclass of a class cluster class. Apple describes this in the linked article. It is a pain, though, since you need to implement all methods from `UIColor` and forward calls to them to a valid `UIColor` instance. Additionally, I couldn't manage to get this to work with `UIColor`, since some of its required initializers are defined in an extension, which you cannot override.

Therefore, the easiest way to go is to just create a wrapper class, which wraps a `UIColor` property. This is not quite as elegant as a subclass, since you cannot use your custom class in place of a `UIColor`, but it works:

```swift
class MyColor {

    var base: UIColor

    ....
}

let myColor = MyColor()
/* we can't use myColor as a UIColor, but have to use myColor.base instead */
```